# Google maps share location

Tags: google-maps

Right now i'm using google maps API at my website.On google maps at web desktop we can click location and share it.

It possible to add this share location function at my website that i use google maps API?

Comment: Can you actually rephrase your question so that users can understand what you want? See this guide to [ask good questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is a feature request in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62938530. You can star it to add your vote.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to use the "share my location" functionality from the [Google Maps Website](https://www.google.com/maps/) with the Google Maps API.

First of all, there is no implementation of this in any of the Maps APIs. You would have to program this yourself.

In any case, you could share location of a POI(point of interest) or any public place, but in the case you wan't to share Users location you can't do this because it's against the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#9-license-requirements):

> 9.3 End User Terms and Privacy Policy. If you develop a Maps API Implementation for use by other users, you must:
>
> c. protect the privacy and legal rights of those users.
>
> Geolocation privacy
>   Your Maps API Implementation must notify the user in advance of the type(s) of data that you intend to collect from the user or the user’s device. Your Maps API Implementation must not obtain or cache any user’s location in any manner except with the user's prior consent. Your Maps API Implementation must let the user revoke the user's consent at any time.

and

> C. Cookies. As noted in the Documentation, certain Maps API(s) store and access cookies and other information on end users’ devices. If you use any of these cookie-enabled Maps API(s) in your Maps API Implementation, then for end users in the European Union, you must comply with the EU User Consent Policy.